# VkAPI выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток!
Есть код написанный на python и компилирован в exe
Есть приложение на c# которое вызывает его

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath + "\\pars\\";
        proc.FileName = "pars.exe";
        proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.Arguments = "/ids_пользователя /сервисный_ключ";
       // proc.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo = proc;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

При запуске выкидывает ошибку VkAPI error 5. При запуске pars.exe с теми же параметрами из cmd все работает

Comment: Вы же прочитали, что за ошибка VKAPI error 5?

Comment: Проблема исправлена. И да я прочитал что это за ошибка. Это ошибка "неверный токен"